# How can we convert string into array in php?

Tags: php

I have a string as mention below

```
$string = 20181123091338,20181130070940;
```

Now, I want to convert this string into an array format like

```
$array = array("20181123091338","20181130070940");
```

So, How can I do this? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php or explode `str_getcsv` will be more accurate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) .

**Try this**

```
$string = "20181123091338,20181130070940";
$arr = explode(",", $string);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($arr);
```

**Explaination**

Here we are exploding string by ","(comma), so we are passing ,(comma) as first parameter in explode function and string passing as second parameter.

Comment: it show me `Array ( [0] => 20181123091338 [1] => 20181130070940 )` but I want this formate `array("20181123091338","20181130070940")` @shubham715

Comment: both is same @Bruce. Array always maintain keys , if you create array like this array("20181123091338","20181130070940") and then print outout , it will be same like above output.